# How easily to select multiple cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

How do I select multiple cells in Google Sheets (non related cells, other cells between them)?

In MS Excel I just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click on all the cells, in Google Sheets it doesn't work.

Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 6):

### Adjacent

As of 11-02-2014, it is possible to select multiple cells, even the ones that aren't adjacent and perform different actions like:

- Styling
- Delete values
- Undo/redo actions
- Paste values (into all cells)
- Apply a quick sum
- Work with formulas and charts

### Screenshot

[image]

### Note

This is only possible with the new Google Spreadsheets.

### References

- https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/TUltIeMntog/2EfOq_f01lEJ
- https://support.google.com/drive/answer/46973?hl=en
- http://googledrive.blogspot.nl/2013/12/newsheets.html

Comment: But how do you past? (ctrl+v doesn't work on edge)

Answer (score 4):

In Google Docs spreadsheets it is only possible to select a single cell or ranges of adjacent cells. So in short NO, you cannot.

Comment: So... Stupid... :/

Thanks for the answer, though!

Comment: Nowadays, this answer is obsolete. See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/56873/88163