# Select words that are not adjacent in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

Is there a way to select words that are not all together like you can with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key in Word? Sorry if this is obvious, but I haven't been able to find an answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

This is rather dated (28 July 2011) but I fear is still applicable:

> I would like to be able to control click in order select multiple bits of text>> You and thousands of others. I'm afraid it isn't supported but I'd like to see it in the future.

[Gill](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/iLsuC08VG_Y)

There is a list of available keyboard shortcuts [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/iLsuC08VG_Y).

Selecting multiple cells in a spreadsheet [is possible](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28438/how-to-easily-select-multiple-cells-in-google-spreadsheets).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know when this feature was implemented, but in 2022, it *is* possible to select several non-contiguous words by maintaining the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key pressed and double-clicking on each word or dragging the cursor on a selection.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

[here](https://plus.google.com/app/basic/stream/z13xyxgb2w24jttc123tifybcy3aivgie04) is a resource that may be of help to you. Selecting non-adjacent cells has been added as a functionality to the New Google Sheets. If you are still using Classic sheets, this will not apply, although updating to New sheets is not difficult.